# Adding custom script for client side validation in SXA

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA 1.7.1

I have added the below javascript for client-side validation in SXALayout.cshtml page:

[image]

Unfortunately, I am getting `XA is not defined` error:

[image]

Comment: It's against best practices to modify the layout included with SXA. There is probably a different way to do this.

Comment: How is this related to Sitecore.Forms?

Comment: yes, its realted to sitecore 9 forms

Comment: If this is related to Sitecore Forms then you shouldn't touch SXALayout view. You are probably following article from Jason here -> https://citizensitecore.com/2017/12/13/sitecore-9-forms-and-ajax-with-sxa/ . Mind that it was created for different version of SXA where Ajax was not supported and this small "hack" was made as a quick fix for that problem.

Comment: I would follow articles similar to this one https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/ and create jquery validation on existing field in your separate js file. Add that file into your theme in SXA and make sure it's loaded as last one. Should do the trick without fiddling around OOTB files which is bad practice and you should avoid it.

Comment: In which location we have to add that script file

Comment: In the `scripts` item in your theme -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/themes/the_sxa_themes

Comment: i got it, i applied my custom function , its working fine.

Comment: ex: /sitecore/media library/Themes/Wireframe/scripts/

Comment: I created an answer from my comments @PrakashLakshmanan. Please upvote and mark it as accepted if you are satisfied with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change views which come OOTB unless it is really necessary.

I would recommend creating js file with your custom scripts and adding that file into your theme in SXA. Make sure it's loaded as last one.

Follow this great tutorial on Sitecore Doc site -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/themes/the_sxa_themes

Location of file would be /sitecore/media library/Themes/{theme_name}/scripts/

e.g. /sitecore/media library/Themes/Wireframe/scripts/

if you are using Wireframe theme.